# fatal error: sodium.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, installation, libsodium

Thank you @stark I was unaware you had to link the directory as part of #include. This part is now working though when I include.

```
(sodium_init() < 0)
    {
        printf("Sodium could not be initialized");
        return 1;
    }
```

I now receive the error "undefined reference to 'sodium_init'.

I have tried adding -lsodium to the compile command (gcc -g -lsodium file1.c file2.c file1.h -o file1.c.exe) which gives the error.

"cannot find -lsodium collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status"

Through further searching I believe I need to tell the compiler where to find -lsodium though cannot find out how.

-- below has been solved using @stark advice --
I have been trying to get the sodium library working for the last 3 days. I have followed the instillation instructions here(https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/installation) which all appear to have completed successfully, but still receive the error.

I then found information suggesting I have not linked Visual Studio (community edition) to the library location.

I have attempted to follow the instructions here(https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a2-using-libraries-with-visual-studio-2005-express/) but cannot see "VC++ Directories". I have tried several other sets of directions with the same outcome.

Is anyone able to help getting the sodium library working so I can get access to the RtlGenRandom() function?

Comment: The website link you cited has several different instructions depending upon your platform and situation. Exactly which steps did you perform? I downloaded the zip file that they mentioned, found the solution file (`.sln`) located at the top of the folder structure, opened it with MSVC, and just ran the build. No errors.

Comment: sodium.h is the header file, not the library.  You need to add its directory to the include path.